# What steps are necessary to enable antialiasing when using a QPainter on a QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to draw basic shapes on a QGLWidget. I am trying to enable antialiasing to smooth out the lines, but it is not working.

This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
QGLWidget *widget = ui->renderWidget;

QPainter painter;

widget->makeCurrent();
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);

painter.begin(widget);
```

However, anything drawn with this painter still has jagged edges. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Does your system support multisample framebuffers?

Comment: Yes, it's windows 7, and I've gotten it to work on another Qt project that used QGLWidget without a QPainter, by just enabling GL_MULTISAMPLE.

Comment: The fact that it's Windows 7 is irrelevant, it's whether or not your GPU and drivers support them - but if another project _on the same machine_ worked correctly then it must be OK.  Your example seems to be hinting that you're trying to draw on the widget outside of a `paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)`, or is it just confusing pseudo-code!?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution. When debugging a different issue, I found messages in my debug output to the effect that you can't set renderhints before the call to begin().

The following works:

```
QGLWidget *widget = ui->renderWidget;

QPainter painter;

widget->makeCurrent();
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

painter.begin(widget);

painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try to enable the antialiasing on the complete Widget :

```
QGLWidget::setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Note, you still need `setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)`.

Answer (score 6):

This question is quite old but I still found it on Google. **You shouldn't use `QGLWidget` any more.** Use the newer `QOpenGLWidget`. This renders the scene off-screen rather than creating a native OpenGL window which causes all sorts of issues with resizing layouts. This code works for me. Put it in your `QGraphicsView` constructor:

```
QOpenGLWidget* gl = new QOpenGLWidget;
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setSamples(8);
gl->setFormat(fmt);
setViewport(gl);
setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work on PyQt5, you will typically subclass `QOpenGLWidget()` to build your own GPU-powered widget. To turn on anti-aliasing, have a look at the code snippet below:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyFigureClass(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        fmt = QSurfaceFormat()    # -╷
        fmt.setSamples(8)         #  > anti-aliasing
        self.setFormat(fmt)       # -╵
        [...]

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        [...]
        qp.end()
```

<sub>Note: Thank you @Timmmm for your answer. I found the PyQt5 solution when looking at your C++ code snippets.</sub>