# How to draw smoothly using QPainter, QOpenGLPaintDevice and QOpenGLWidget on retina display?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qpainter

The drawing is very laggy when I try to draw using `QWidget` and `QPainter`. I decided to accelerate the drawing by using `QOpenGLPaintDevice` and `QOpenGLWidget`. But the rounded corners of shapes are very rude, comparing to drawing on regular widget.

QWidget:

[image]

QOpenGLWidget:

[image]

Here is a code how I setup the QOpenGLPaintDevice.

```
QOpenGLPaintDevice* device = nullptr;

void QOpenGLWorkspaceWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    initDeviceIfNeed();
    handleResize(this, w, h);
    int ratio = devicePixelRatio();
    device->setSize(QSize(w * ratio, h * ratio));
    device->setDevicePixelRatio(ratio);
}

void QOpenGLWorkspaceWidget::initDeviceIfNeed() {
    if (!device) {
        device = new QOpenGLPaintDevice();
        drawer->setPaintDevice(device);
    }
}

void QOpenGLWorkspaceWidget::paintGL() {
    initDeviceIfNeed();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    workspaceDrawer->draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here

[What steps are necessary to enable antialiasing when using a QPainter on a QGLWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971428/what-steps-are-necessary-to-enable-antialiasing-when-using-a-qpainter-on-a-qglwi)

`openGlWidget.setSamples(8)` and `painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)`
did the job.